# Coldfusion 2021 Update 5 breaks xml

Tags: coldfusion

I just applied update 5 and now I am getting XML errors:

"Error","ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8020-exec-10","10/13/22","11:28:42","Medlists3","coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlSearch(Lcoldfusion/xml/XmlNodeList;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2021-update-5.html  says

> CHANGE IN XML
>
> If the XML path contains a forward slash or backslash, it will be
> blocked. The flag, coldfusion.xml.allowPathCharacters, must be set to
> true to allow the same.

But I don't know where to make this change.

Comment: Does the error message include the line number?

Comment: It does, but it is not helpful.  The error is occuring on all of our apps that use Mach II framework which has the config in an xml file

Comment: There is some discussion on the CFML Slack channel about this as well.  FYI.

Comment: FWIW, there are two problems related to XML as of the Oct 2022 CF updates. The OP's error here is about the change and problem related to the xmlsearch function...but then he quotes the release notes about the "Coldfusion.xml.allowPathCharacter" flag. That (a jvm argument) applies instead to the OTHER xml change, related primarily to the xmltransform function. Definitely easy to confuse the two. Hope my distinction of them here will help some readers finding this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question was asked on CFML Slack and it was said that you needed to manually clear all .class files from disk since the bytecode is not binary compatible.

Comment: I posted on adobe forums and got the same correct answer:  https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/coldfusion-2021-update-5-breaks-xml/m-p/13265555  RaviShankar Chagnur
Adobe Employee , 38m ago

Hello Gabriel,

 

Please try this.
 Update ColdFusion 2021 with update 5

Go to \ColdFusion2021\{instances}\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cfclasses and clear the classes. 
Restart ColdFusion service and try again.

Comment: Gabriel, thanks for sharing the added detail. That's really helpful for folks who may not deal with the problem enough to know where to "manually clear all .class files", which could be misinterpreted by a casual reader. :-)

Answer (score 4):

A legacy Fusebox 5 coldfusion application got this exact error. Following up on gabriel's note: after deleting the contents of cfclasses, I had to restart the Coldfusion 2021 Application in services (Windows Server 2019) in order for the contents of cfclasses to refresh. After the restart, the application worked as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe added the following comment for the patch notes for CF2018 Update 15, but they said that this shouldn't be an issue in ColdFusion 2021-

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2018-update-15.html

--

**Known issues in this release**
If you encounter the following error message, clear the classes in <CF_HOME>/instance/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfclasses.

*"coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlSearch(Lcoldfusion/xml/XmlNodeList;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; The specific sequence of files included or processed is: \<filepath>, line: 34 "
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlSearch(Lcoldfusion/xml/XmlNodeList;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;*

- If the Uninstall button is disabled on Update 15, uninstall the
  update using the uninstaller.jar present in the hf-updates folder.
- your application uses the functions XmlSearch and XmlTransform,
  you'll have to recompile the files after applying Update 15.

--

Comment: You are correct, and from now on I will also check the CF2018 update pages.... but lovely adobe did NOT include that on https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2021-update-5.html... I wish I could give you both credit

Answer (score 1):

I added the variable "-Dcoldfusion.xml.allowPathCharacters=true" in Java JVM arguments and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the answer that helped me. In response to the community bot, launch the ColdFusion Admin in the web browser, navigate to Server Settings > Java and JVM. Then scroll down to the "JVM Arguments" section and add the argument listed in quotes in this answer to the box (make sure you have a space before it and the prior arguments). Save the changes and restart the ColdFusion service.

Comment: There are two problems related to XML as of the Oct 2022 CF updates. While this one about the JVM arg applies to problems with xmltransform, the OP is asking about an error with xmlsearch (but mistakenly quotes the discussion of the jvm arg). So this is indeed the right answer to "where to put that jvm arg", but it's not the right answer to the original question of how to solve the xmlsearch problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your Coldfusion Administrator, under Server Settings, Java and JVM, in the JVM Arguments box, append the following to the end (make sure there is a space after the last entry:

-Dcoldfusion.xml.allowPathCharacters=true

Then restart the CF Service.

Took care of the problem for us.

Comment: There are two problems related to XML as of the Oct 2022 CF updates. While this one about the JVM arg applies to problems with xmltransform, the OP is asking about an error with xmlsearch (but mistakenly quotes the discussion of the jvm arg). So this is indeed the right answer to "where to put that jvm arg", but it's not the right answer to the original question of how to solve the xmlsearch problem. :-)

Comment: Thanks @mpelant. This solution worked for me when I encountered an error with a CF2023 website: "An error occurred while Transforming an XML document. Unable to process the XML string as it could probably contain file paths."   We never had this issue before, so it may have been a result of upgrading to CF2023. Either way, your suggest of the JVM setting solved the error for us.