# Coldfusion 2018 Update 19 breaks xml

Tags: coldfusion

I just applied update 19 and now I am getting XML errors:

Message coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlSearch(Lcoldfusion/xml/XmlNodeList;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

StackTrace
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlSearch(Lcoldfusion/xml/XmlNodeList;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; at cfseatCharts_functions2ecfm737404277$funcBUILDSEATCHARTSTRUCT.runFunction(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestWeb\Test\TestCustomer\Apps\SupSystems\seatCharts_functions.cfm:52) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:554) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:448) at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95) ......

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2018-update-19.html says

```
<CFSET LOCAL.xml = xmlParse(ARGUMENTS.data)>
<CFSET LOCAL.seatChart = {
    rows = [],
    cols = [],
    seats = [],
    labels = []
}>

<CFSET LOCAL.nodes = xmlSearch(LOCAL.xml, "/seatchart/rows/row")>

<CFLOOP ARRAY="#LOCAL.nodes#" ITEM="currItem">
    <CFSET arrayAppend(LOCAL.seatChart.rows, currItem.xmlAttributes)>
</CFLOOP>

<CFSET LOCAL.nodes = xmlSearch(LOCAL.xml, "/seatchart/cols/col")>
<CFLOOP ARRAY="#LOCAL.nodes#" ITEM="curritem">
    <CFSET arrayAppend(LOCAL.seatChart.cols, currItem.xmlAttributes)>
</CFLOOP>

<CFSET LOCAL.nodes = xmlSearch(LOCAL.xml, "/seatchart/seats/seat")>
<CFLOOP ARRAY="#LOCAL.nodes#" ITEM="currItem">
    <CFSET arrayAppend(LOCAL.seatChart.seats, currItem.xmlAttributes)>
</CFLOOP>

<CFSET LOCAL.nodes = xmlSearch(LOCAL.xml, "/seatchart/labels/label")>
<CFLOOP ARRAY="#LOCAL.nodes#" ITEM="currItem">
    <CFSET arrayAppend(LOCAL.seatChart.labels, currItem.xmlAttributes)>
</CFLOOP>

<CFRETURN LOCAL.seatChart>
```

Comment: In your CF installation folder, go to cfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfclasses and clear this folder. Restart services and try again

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the same situation as with [Coldfusion 2021 Update 5 breaks xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74058674/894061), with details in https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2018-update-15.html:

> Known issues in this release
> If you encounter the following error message, clear the classes in <CF_HOME>/instance/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfclasses.

```
"coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlSearch(Lcoldfusion/xml/XmlNodeList;
Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
The specific sequence of files included or processed is: \\<ip>\<filepath>, line: 34 "
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlSearch(Lcoldfusion/xml/XmlNodeList;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Tip: you can enable youself a bit more by googling your error messages. Even googling "coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.XmlSearch" was enough to find the answer to this.